# Writing a query where I don't know the depth of it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume I have dynamic database structure as,

```
{
    id: 1,
    members: {
        name: "x",
        members: {
            name: "y",
            members: {
                name: "da",
                id: 21
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Actually, I don't know the `depth` of members inside members. It's `dynamic`. But I search for value of `members.id`. How can I write a query where I don't know the exact structure of tree?
`members.id: 21` doesn't give the document.

I mean I want something like `members...id: 21`

So what do you suggest?